# Xorg server memory leak observed due to Qt application on Ubuntu Unity and XFCE

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu-16.04, xorg, xfce

We run following test to create window, show window and close window and observed that Xorg RES memory or you can say Main memory is swelling on each creation, show and deletion of window.

we just run below code and click on pushButton

Note: We have tried both delete and deleteLater call in slot dummy. But we still see Xorg memory growing over time. This leads to RAM outage.

Following is the code snippet

MainWindow.h header file

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "QTimer"


namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    void dummy();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QTimer *m_timer;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "qdialog.h"
#include "QThread"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    m_timer = new QTimer();
    connect(m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(dummy()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::dummy()
{
     MainWindow *dialog;
    dialog = new MainWindow();
    dialog->show();
     QThread::msleep(500);
     //delete(dialog);
     dialog->deleteLater();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   m_timer->start(1000);
}
```

Following is the UI file used

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1053</width>
    <height>726</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>99</width>
      <height>27</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>PushButton</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>90</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>841</width>
      <height>381</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1053</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You should contact Qt and/or Xorg to file a bug. StackOverflow is not the proper place for bug reports.

Comment: I just want to check. Am I doing anything wrong in shared code?